# Snowflake - Convert varchar to numeric

Tags: type-conversion, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, varchar

I have a column(field1) defined as varchar in snowflake. It is storing both string and numbers(ex values: US15876, 1.106336965E9). How can I convert the numeric values to display something like 1106336965, without losing the columns that is storing string values or null values. I am trying try_to_numeric(field1), but this is eliminating the record with string values and showing them as null. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `try_to_number` is the way to have numbers, and nulls for non-number without errors. But if you want to keep the strings, you actually have to convert your newly create number, back to text (or variant), otherwise it cannot be in the same column, so nothing is gained:

```
select column1
    ,try_to_number(column1) as_num
    ,nvl(as_num::text, column1) as why_not_both
from values
  ('US15876'), 
  ('1.106336965E9'),
  ('1.106336965'),
  ('1106336965');
```

| COLUMN1 | AS_NUM | WHY_NOT_BOTH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US15876 | null | US15876 |
| 1106336965 | 1,106,336,965 | 1106336965 |
| 1.106336965 | 1 | 1 |
| 1106336965 | 1,106,336,965 | 1106336965 |

Comment: I too have a varchar column woth commas..example- “1,1111”. I’m using try_to_number() but it gives me error saying that it cannot convert numeric to timestamp. My destination table has the correct data type though ie number.. any reason why the transformation is failing? Thanks